# Why does function c() accept an undocumented argument?

Tags: r, function, arguments

The documentation for the base function `c()` shows its default arguments as

```
c(..., recursive = FALSE)
```

Now, if we define

```
lst <- list(x = 1:5, y = 6:10)
```

and then combine the list with

```
c(lst, recursive = TRUE)
# x1 x2 x3 x4 x5 y1 y2 y3 y4 y5 
#  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9 10
```

the list is collapsed, and the names are kept.

But we can also use another, undocumented argument, `use.names`, to remove the names.

```
c(lst, recursive = TRUE, use.names = FALSE)
# [1]  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9 10
```

**Why isn't** `use.names` **documented as one of the arguments of** `c()` ?

Comment: Just to close the loop on this, `use.names=` in `c()` was documented in R 3.3.2 (https://cran.r-project.org/doc/manuals/r-devel/NEWS.html).  There's a thread on this at http://r.789695.n4.nabble.com/Undocumented-use-names-argument-to-c-td4724919.html

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I think that it is due to the `recursive=TRUE` which I believe must use the same code as `unlist`. The `use.names` parameter is described in `?unlist`.

Comment: They seem to have [non-overlapping code paths](https://github.com/wch/r-source/blob/d149090b0bfd093a13686954219bee24da5ee9de/src/main/bind.c#L839) in the source.

Comment: I saw that. I wonder if it was an accidental inclusion? The behavior of c( ..., recursive=TRUE) certainly seems to mimic what I usually use `unlist` to accomplish.

Comment: But it's odd that they check for the parameter values differently. So it's not like a copy/paste thing. As with all undocumented stuff, it's probably best not to rely on that behavior incase it changes. `Unlist` is probably the better option here.

Comment: At one point Prof Ripley said that c() and unlist() 'shared code':http://markmail.org/search/?q=list%3Aorg.r-project+use.names+unlist#query:list%3Aorg.r-project%20use.names%20unlist%20from%3A%22Prof%20Brian%20Ripley%22+page:1+mid:oa7eemipgkm5ulfj+state:results

Comment: Well, going through the history, i can see that `do_c` has changed recently. I can't find where it overlaps with `do_unlist` though.

Comment: @BondedDust -- Nice catch! [Here, from July 30, 1998](https://github.com/wch/r-source/commit/8fee9de69de30815457992145657797bf793b74f), is where `do_c` got split into `do_c` and `do_unlist`.

Comment: Catch? More like "Lucky guess". (I did try to search the Language Definition without success. I found the `unlist` citation using `sos::findFn("use.names")`)

Comment: The code was formerly shared but has been (long time passing) separated. The `use.names` parameter was apparently left in when that occurred, but not documented.

Comment: `identical(c(a=1L, b=2L, use.names=FALSE), 1:2)`!

Answer (score 3):

`c` is an S4 Generic function, which means that a different function is called depending on its arguments.

Not all of those functions take the argument `use.names`, so it does not make sense for it to be documented in the documentation for `c()`.

Comment: It's odd that's in the [default function do_c_dflt](https://github.com/wch/r-source/blob/d149090b0bfd093a13686954219bee24da5ee9de/src/main/bind.c#L754) but it's not document like "recursive" is. They aren't treated any differently in the source code.

Comment: I don't buy that explanation (or at least I won't without some more supporting evidence!) Here's why: (1) `c()` is as much an S3 function as it is an S4 function; compare the results of `methods("c")` and `showMethods("c")` in a fresh R session. (2) `recursive=` is no more universally supported by `c()` methods than is `use.names=`; what does `recursive=` do in `c.numeric_version()`? (3) S4 generics often have just a few arguments, they seem to typically be documented; why the exception here, when `use.names` is one of just three formal arguments passed into the underlying C function?

Comment: `c` is a primitive function, not S4!

Comment: @lebatsnok, If you look at the output of `?c`, it says `This is a primitive function`, but it also says further down that `This function is S4 generic`.

Comment: @merlin - I think the help page is confusing here. you can define S4 methods for  `c` (I tried, it works) with  `setMethod` but you can also define S3 methods. When you define an S4 generic in an ordinary way and call it, say, `foo` then `isS4(foo)` will be TRUE. Not for `c`.

Comment: But you seem to have a point. When you define a new S4 class, and a `c` method for that class (with `setMethod`) without explicitly defining `use.names` and `recursive` arguments then `c(..., use.names=TRUE)` will give an error but not `c(..., recursive=TRUE)`.

Comment: @lebatsnok, I agree that the help page is confusing. Thank you for all the clarifications.