# How to specify arguments after dots ... in R?

Tags: r

This probably comes down to 'how to pass optional parameters to R functions'.
Take `c()` for example. It's definition is:

```
c(..., recursive = FALSE)
```

However, if I use it like this `c(1:5, TRUE)` it gives `[1] 1 2 3 4 5 1` which is perfectly understandable, but also a bit strange since I'd expect it to be simple to figure out. I guess it IS simple and I'm simply not seeing the whole thing.

Cheers for answering and not raging. I googled and searched SO, but probably got too many wrong answered and gave up.

EDIT: edited due to illogical example.

Comment: If the argument is after the dots you should name it.

Comment: Rather, if the argument is after dots you **must** name it. `c(1:5, recursive = FALSE)`.

Comment: Perfect. I started learning from set of classes I stumbled on and it seems to be some kind of a crash course... and so I crashed :)

Comment: In addition, `FALSE` is the default.  The `recursive` argument is really useless in the manner you're using it.  It's more for concatenating list items.  `c(as.list(1:5), recursive=TRUE)`.  It's also worth adding that arguments are **not** partially matched after `...`.  You have to write the entire name

Comment: Thanks Richard for pointing it out. I was aiming at 'how to set the optional argument' actually. Still a good point - I edited the post.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I was waiting to see if any of the first commenters were going to answer, but they haven't so I will.

Since in the definition of `c()` the first argument is `...`, you must completely name any arguments that follow for them to work correctly.  I say arguments plural and not argument singular because there is actually a second, undocumented argument in `c()`. See [Why does function c() accept an undocumented argument?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24815572/why-does-function-c-accept-an-undocumented-argument) for more on that. For arguments that come before `...`, you can use partial argument matching, but for those after `...` you must write the complete argument name.

What's happening in your example is that you are concatenating the numeric value of `TRUE` (which is 1) to the vector `1:5`

```
as.numeric(TRUE)            ## numeric value of TRUE
# [1] 1
c(1:5, TRUE)                ## try no arg name, wrong result
# [1] 1 2 3 4 5 1
c(1:5, rec=TRUE)            ## try partial arg matching, wrong result
#                    rec 
#  1   2   3   4   5   1
```

Furthermore, `recursive` really does nothing in the manner that you're attempting to use it.

```
c(1:5)
# [1] 1 2 3 4 5
c(1:5, recursive=TRUE)      ## 1:5 not recursive, same result
# [1] 1 2 3 4 5
is.recursive(c(1:5))
# [1] FALSE
```

It's more for concatenating list items, or any other recursive objects (see `?is.recursive`).

```
(x <- as.list(1:5))
# [[1]]
# [1] 1
# 
# [[2]]
# [1] 2
# 
# [[3]]
# [1] 3
# 
# [[4]]
# [1] 4
# 
# [[5]]
# [1] 5
is.recursive(x)
# [1] TRUE
c(x, recursive=TRUE)        ## correct usage on recursive object x
# [1] 1 2 3 4 5
```

Comment: Congrats for the 20K (plus one)

Comment: Another congrats for the 20K. :)

Comment: thanks so much for the answer. Turned out to be upvoted for several times, as well as the question. not really sure why 3 close suggestions arose. people are always trigger happy.