# Internal options in R

Tags: r

Sometimes I find R functions that have undocumented options like `use.names` in `c`:

```
x <- c(a = 1, b = 2, c = 3, d = 4)
y <- c(e = 5, f = 6, g = 7, e = 8, h = 9)

print(c(x, y))
# a b c d e f g e h 
# 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 

print(c(x, y, i = 10))
# a  b  c  d  e  f  g  e  h  i 
# 1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9 10 

print(c(x, y, use.names = F))
# [1] 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9
```

Are there any way of checking this `.Internal` or `.Primitive` function options? Is there any danger in their use, like random changes in the API?

Comment: Similar: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24815572/why-does-function-c-accept-an-undocumented-argument, but does not answer the question about dangers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Today (2021, R4.1) the `use.names` option is officially [documented](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/c.html).

The only way to check the implementation of .Internal or .Primitive R functions is to inspect the R source - for this particular option, [here's the exact line](https://github.com/wch/r-source/blob/80381b60cd96747b2e028d07fc3adbb911702d67/src/main/subassign.c#L856).

As a general rule, undocumented API or API-parts are not a part of the contract between the developers and the users, and so are subject to change at any time. This option *might* have been an experimental feature at some point, and documenting it made it an official part of R.
Alternatively it might have been an unintentional oversight that was fixed sometime later.  After tracking the R development process for a bit, it seems to me both options are equally likely.

---

Edit: I recently learnt of [Jim Hester's "lookup" R package](https://github.com/jimhester/lookup), which uses github API and some heuristics to inspect the R sources *from an R session*. Example:

```
> devtools::install_github("jimhester/lookup")
Downloading GitHub repo jimhester/lookup@HEAD
These packages have more recent versions available.
It is recommended to update all of them.
Which would you like to update?

1: All                                     
2: CRAN packages only                      
3: None                                    
4: gh      (1.3.0 -> f75b0e498...) [GitHub]
5: memoise (2.0.1 -> 3b0bf3e5f...) [GitHub]

Enter one or more numbers, or an empty line to skip updates: 3   # <- just to save time
...

> library("lookup")
...

> is.list   # for example
```

This would open up an editor window with the relevant C code. Note that only the latest R sources are inspected, they typically differ slightly from the sources for the R you're actually running.